# How to get huge string data from http(GET) response using node js without buffering?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, rest, http

I am trying to get XML as string by calling HTTP GET (REST) from node js. I think the server sends the response only once but node receives it in chunks as it comes to res.on('data') multiple times. As i concatenate the multiple chunks, I get my complete data. But this takes a lot of time. I want to get all the data in one go. Please provide your views. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that many XML parsers require the whole string to be loaded into memory *before* they actually begin building an object from the data. That adds another layer of latency that should be considered.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just "get all the data in one go" because that's not how TCP works. So if you're expecting that, then there is going to be some buffering going on at some other layer, whether you're doing it explicitly or not.

If you are going to be parsing the XML you're downloading, then you might look into using an XML parsing module that supports parsing chunks at a time, such as [sax](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js).

Otherwise if you want something more user-friendly (but requires the complete buffered XML string), you might look at using [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) with `xmlMode: true`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I understand that loading the whole XML into memory will consume memory and it will be buffered at one layer or the other. But I need that as i need to pass it to Sigma.js to draw a UI component. Also, when I say the data is buffered, it's not broken by tags/nodes but the string is truncated and received in parts. So it's of no use to me unless I append all the parts. Also, I am not trying to parse the XML, the XML string is formed on server side and sent as response to node js.

Thanks again.